# phone number and email on left side of shopping basket

Tags: magento-1.7, home

please visit this " http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/"

this is galagiftshop theme

I need to to Put "Email us" and  "phone no" on left side of shopping cart basket.

let me know if you have any queries.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a Static Block from admin Panel . You can use one Static Block for the both Email-us and Phone No .

Please make sure from where you are using the cart basket html .

Just before that call the Static block you had created for the Email-us and Phone No.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('email-phone')->toHtml(); ?>
```

This will get the Static Block HTML of Email and Phone no before Cart Basket.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, can we gie link inside static block, please visit "http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/"
here for E-mail us, i gave href link in static block, but its working, how to give link for text, which insidestatic block....

Comment: Can you please share me the code that you are using in the Static Block for the anchor tag to the text ?

Comment: check here : http://pastebin.com/gryDGrQx  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('galagiftshop_header_ad');?> this block

Comment: Are you sure your using Static Block for the Email us in the header.phtml because in code it shows that your including the external file by getChildHtml function (<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('galagiftshop_header_ad');?>) . If your using the static block inside the (galagiftshop_header_ad) file then please share me the code of the Static Block where you had used Email us text.

Comment: no, i am not....

Comment: i am using external file only.... please help me to give link for email us in http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/

Comment: Please share me a code where your using a Email us text . Beacause i need to check if issue with your php tags or not . So let me know about it.

Comment: i enabled template path hints, please vist now and tell me where is the code.

Comment: Please turn off the Php template hints .

Comment: yes, i done......

Comment: frontend/default/galagiftshop/template/page/html/em_head.phtml  , Can you check in this file .

Comment: I checked your site , I think its done .

Comment: not yet done, em_head.phtml see => http://pastebin.com/tT6d47nT

Comment: But in your site the Email us is now clickable and its redirect to the mail client for sending mail .

Comment: but i can't  able to "css/move" to top of "sign in"

Comment: You want the Email us to the next of the Signin text ??  Then its a css issue and I cant find the Phone no as well in your text , But i can see it in the Firebug window.

Comment: If you want that file then you have to search <block type="<some-text>" as="galagiftshop_header_ad" name="<some-text>" template="<some-text>"> in page.xml or local.xml of your package and theme folder .

Comment: pleae help me , i really need your help now : check the site boards.newtrendzonline.com now, i added line <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-phone')->toHtml‌​‌​(); ?> in header.phtml = > pastebin.com/gy6TLyNq but email is not linking

Comment: Can u share the code of static block that you wrote in the admin panel of identifier as header-phone ???

Comment: Actually the link works, but there is a div over it. The div with class grid_24 header-bottom. Try to re-position it so it won't go over your block - Marius.  please check file = http://pastebin.com/gy6TLyNq and tell me where i have to place the code.

Comment: I had checked your site in the Firebug . Just remove the anchor tag outside the p tag of the phone number and add a new p tag for the email address.

Comment: visit the link now, problem with placing the code here: please check the file: http://pastebin.com/gy6TLyNq

Comment: hi, right now some how the problem solved. finally using trail and error method, i placed code in somewhere and its working. 

Thanks a lot again.....

Comment: Thanks a lot Programmer_kit and Rahul both of the answers are correct here. as Rahul spend more time on this, and Rahul  is having less reputation than Programmer_rkt, I want to vote for Rahul answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two static blocks for this and put those static blocks in appropriate position in the layout.

Let us assume your static blocks are `header-email` and `header-phone`. In that case, you can use the following code in appropriate position in `header.phtml`(I am not sure about this template file. But most probably it should be the template file that renders those parts).

File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/page/html/header.phtml`

```
<div>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-phone')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-email')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

You need to invoke this code snippets in appropriate postion in `header.phtml`. Also you may need to do some css works in order to make them align well

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply, i will try, be with me, thanks....

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, can we gie link inside static block, please visit "http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/"
here for E-mail us, i gave href link in static block, but its working, how to give link for text, which insidestatic block....

Comment: I think you can put link through static block itself. put `<a href="some/path/to/go" title="Some text">Some text</a>` inside static block.

Comment: where did you insert static block? inside `header.phtml` ?

Comment: yes....   in header.phtml

Comment: hi, email link is not working, please help me.

Comment: pleae help me , i really need your help now : check the site boards.newtrendzonline.com now, i added line <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header-phone')->toHtml‌​‌​(); ?> in header.phtml = > pastebin.com/gy6TLyNq but email is not linking

Comment: hi, right now some how the problem solved. finally using trail and error method, i placed code in somewhere and its working. 

Thanks a lot again.....

Comment: Thanks a lot Programmer_kit and Rahul both of the answers are correct here. as Rahul spend more time on this, and Rahul  is having less reputation than Programmer_rkt, I want to vote for Rahul answer as correct.